# Updating edge attributes of a large dense graph

Tags: graph, networkx

I have a large and dense graph whose edge attributes are updated using the following code. Briefly, I set the edge attributes based on some calculations on the values fetched from other dictionaries (degdict, pifeadict, nodeneidict etc). My smallest graph has 15 million edges. When the execution reaches this stage, the CPU usage dips as low as 10% and memory hikes up to 69%. For large graphs, my process is getting killed because of 90% memory usage. I am not sure where things are going wrong.

In addition to fixing this memory problem, I also need to speed up this loop, if possible - perhaps, a parallel solution to update the edge attributes. Please suggest solutions.

```
    for fauth, sauth in Gcparam.edges_iter():
        first_deg = degdict[fauth]
        sec_deg = degdict[sauth]
        paval = float(first_deg*sec_deg)/float(currmaxdeg * \
                                                         currmaxdeg)
        try:
            f2 = dmpdict[first_deg][sec_deg]
        except KeyError:
            f2 = 0.0
        try:
            pival = pifeadict[first_deg][sec_deg]
        except KeyError:
            pival = 0.0
        delDval = float(abs(first_deg - sec_deg))/(float(currmaxdeg)*delT)
        f5 = calc_comm_kws(fauth, sauth, kwsdict)
        avg_ndeg = getAvgNeiDeg(fauth, sauth, nodeneidict, currmaxdeg)/delT
        prop = getPropensity(fauth, sauth, nodeneidict, currmaxdeg, Gparam)/delT
        tempdict = {'years':[year], 'pa':[paval],\
                        'dmp':[f2], 'pi':[pival], 'deld':[delDval],\
                        'delndeg':[avg_ndeg], 'delprop' :[prop],\
                        'ck' :[f5]
                       }
        Gcparam[fauth][sauth].update(tempdict)
```

Comment: Storing 15 million dictionaries like your "tempdict" is the memory issue.  You might try reducing the data you store there.  Do you need to store a list for every dict value?  E.g. can you use 'years':year instead of 'years':[year].

Comment: @Aric: A typical attribute data for an edge goes as follows: {'years':[t1 t2 t3], 'attr1':[x y z], 'attr2':[a b c]}. So, yes, I need to have [year] as I accumulate data from a growing graph.

Comment: @Aric: I am storing the 15M dicts one each for an edge. Are you suggesting that storing complex python objects as edge attributes is not memory efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can estimate the amount of storage you need for the data on each edge like this:

```
In [1]: from pympler.asizeof import asizeof

In [2]: tempdict = {'years':[1900], 'pa':[1.0],\
                        'dmp':[2.0], 'pi':[3.0], 'deld':[7],\
                        'delndeg':[3.4], 'delprop' :[7.5],\
                        'ck' :[22.0]
}

In [3]: asizeof(tempdict)
Out[3]: 1000
```

So it looks like 1000 bytes is a lower bound for what you are doing.  Multiply that by the number of edges for the total.
NetworkX also has some overhead for the node and edge data structures which depends on what type of object you use for nodes.  Integers are smallest.

Comment: thanks for introducing pympler. It looks like I have to look for other programming paradigms - I just don't have 15G memory. Btw, my nodes are strings. Or, perhaps I should look at making numpy arrays as edge attributes. Is this possible?

Comment: So, I can add a numpy array as an edge attribute, however a plain numpy array takes only 80 bytes and in the form an edge attribute it takes 408 bytes, which is still less than 1000.